# How to use data returned by $http request for another request in same controller using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am making a function that makes a http GET request, and then uses part of that response to make another http GET request. However, the data being returned by the first http GET request is wrapped in a lot of unnecessary data (maybe its a promise object), but I just need the json component of it. How do I access the json data of my response in the controller? Here is my code.

```
 $scope.doSearch = function() {
    var upcResult = Restangular.one('upc',$scope.searchTerm).get()

//the upc returns an item, so i am trying to access that part of the json by using      
  upcResult.item, how if I console.log that it is undefined

$scope.doAnotherSearch = function() {
    var itemResult = Restangular.one('item',upcResult.item).get();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promise chain.

```
var upcResult = Restangular.one('upc',$scope.searchTerm).get();

upcResult.then(function (result) {
  // call other http get
  return Restangular.one('item',result.item).get();
}).then(function (result) {
  //....
});
```

I don't know if in your case `Restangular.one(/*...*/).get();` returns promise but you can wrap it with  `$q` like:

```
 var upcResult = Restangular.one('upc',$scope.searchTerm).get(); 
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 deferred.resolve(upcResult).then(function(){/*...*/});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I was having trouble understanding promises.